# Quartz.net daily jobs keeps getting executed every minute

Tags: scheduling, quartz.net, atlas

I have the code below. I would expect it to run daily at 17:00 if the config setting was not set otherwise the config setting will be used. So far no issue, the variable is set correctly. However: Instead of daily the job gets executed every minute and I cant figure out why. Is the scheduler not set up correctly?

```
        TimeSpan timeOfExecution;

        if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeOfExecution"], out timeOfExecution))
        {
            timeOfExecution = new TimeSpan(17, 0, 0);

        }

       var job = JobBuilder.Create<DailyReportJob>()
            .WithIdentity("DailyReportJob")
            .Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("DailyReportTrigger")
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(s => s.OnEveryDay().StartingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(timeOfExecution.Hours, timeOfExecution.Minutes)))
            .Build();

        Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        Scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(AutofacJobListener);
        Scheduler.Start();
```

Comment: Any news on this side ?

Comment: Apologies. Your answer was correct. I have marked your reply as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default time for this trigger is every minute, since you haven't specified otherwise.

You can check all the intervals using this code:

```
var dt = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (dt == null)
        break;

    Console.WriteLine(dt.Value.ToLocalTime());
    dt = trigger.GetFireTimeAfter(dt);
}
```

If you want to schedule your job to run once a day at 5pm, you can change your code adding a 24 hour interval:

```
var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("DailyReportTrigger")
    .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(s => s.OnEveryDay().StartingDailyAt(new TimeOfDay(timeOfExecution.Hours, timeOfExecution.Minutes)))
    .WithIntervalInHours(24)
    .Build();
```

Comment: I don't understand why the OP's usage of the API is wrong. Why does his code result in a 1 minute schedule by default?